# How to use krsort() with an array of object?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of object like this :

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 527
        [rate] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 530
        [rate] => 25
    )
```

And i'm looking to sort it by rate in reverse ascending order. I tried with krsort() but I don't know how to tell the function to sort it by rate. Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Use `usort` please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `usort` with a simple callback:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $b->rate - $a->rate; });
```

Comment: If answer helps to solve your problem - feel free to __accept__ it.